# How To Add A Panel To Extjs Tab

Tags: extjs, tabs, tabpanel

Am trying to add a panel to tab of a tabpanel (like below)
but i get "Layout run failed" in the console

Any pointers or in general how to add components to the tab
because the examples i see its just html in the tab

Thanks.

```
{
                            xtype: 'tabpanel',
                            activeTab: 0,
                            width: 632,
                            //height: 300,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    title: 'Companies',
                                    layout: 'border',

                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'panel',
                                            region: 'center',
                                            width: 500,
                                            title: 'Tooler',

                                            items: []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'toolbar',
                                            region: 'south',
                                            width: 500,

                                            items: [
                                                '->',
                                                { text: 'Edit Company', action: 'edit' }
                                            ]//toolbar items
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Access Group'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Roles'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Menus'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Forms'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
```

Comment: The tab panel needs a height, either implicitly (from a layout) or explicitly (by specifying a height) because the border layout requires a height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like:

```
{
  xtype:'tabpanel',
  activeTab: 0,
  width: 632,
  height: 300,
  /*
  * -or- instead of specifying height/width,
  * depending on the parent container use a
  * layout e.g. layout:'fit'
  *
  */
  items:[
    {
       xtype:'panel'
       title'tab1',
       /*
       * again, try, e.g. layout:'fit',
       * also note you should put the toolbar here
       * using, e.g. tbar: Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar, {properties, items...}),
       *
       */
       items:[
              ...etc....
       ]

    },
    {
       xtype:'panel'
       title'tab2',
       // again, try, e.g. layout:'fit',
       items:[
              ...etc....
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The general logic is- create a `tabpanel`, each tab is then an item (`panel`) of this tab panel, its `title` text becomes the tab text. You can then set the content of each child panel depending on what they need to show, either by defining their `html`, or by adding further child `items` to them, under their `items` property.

Toolbars should not be specified as an item if possible, but should be defined using the `tbar` property of the component the toolbar is for. If you want a toolbar to appear at the bottom of a panel instead of the top, specify it the same, but use the `bbar` property instead of `tbar`.